# Creating an NPM package out of a Create React App and publish on Gitlab

Tags: npm, gitlab, create-react-app, npm-publish, npm-package

This might be a stupid question but I really don't know what is going on.

I have created a React App with `crate react app` and uploaded it as a private repository to my **GitLab** account. The (default) React App starts as expected after running `yarn start` locally at `localhost:3000`. Since I need to create packages for ongoing code development, I have started to get into using the **NPM Registry** at GitLab. This was actually quite easy:

1. create an `.npmrc` within the app directory
2. add **scope**, **repository ID** and **auth token** (I have chosen to use a personal token) like so

```java
# Set URL for your scoped packages.
# This is my top-level group at GitLab

@scope:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/


# Add the token for the scoped packages URL.
# I have chosen to use the personal key -> more infos: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/

//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken="<auth-token>"


# Add token for uploading to the registry.

//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-ID>/packages/npm/:_authToken="<auth-token>"
```

3. run `npm init` to initialise the package
4. add the **scope** and a **publishConfig** to the `package.json` like so

```java
{
  "name": "@scope/package-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js", <-- the entry point 
  ...
  "publishConfig": {
    "@scope:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-ID>/packages/npm/"
  }
}
```

5. run `npm publish`

Like I've said, the package gets uploaded to my GitLab account, under the *scope* fine. The only problem I have now is that running `yarn start` from my local repo does result in a blank white screen. I have also realised that yarn does not redirect to `http://localhost:3000` anymore but to `http://localhost:3000/scope/repository-name`.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of try and error (and even more research), I have finally found the solution to my problem. I want to point out, that I am still not entirely sure why certain things happen but hopefully this solution will help the one or other from wasting time with this.

#### The goal

Basically, I want to publish certain **React Components** as an **NPM Package** to [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com). I work on a project which contains numerous different React Components - some of which are stand alone Single Page Applications and others are part of an "App". The components which are part of the Application might also be reused later in another project. Thus this qualifies them to be packaged.

Whenever I start developing, I start with `create react app` and since a React App is usually a **Single Page Application,** it does not really make sense to package it. Nonetheless, if we want to develop some components which will be part of an app later, but still want to test the behaviour locally, it makes sense to do so.

I will describe how to create packages on Gitlab but I guess it will work the same (apart from details with authentication and scopes) with any other repository hosting service.

#### The setup

We start with setting up our React App

```
npx create-react-app react-package
```

After everything is installed navigate into application folder `cd react-package` and start with developing a component. For our example we create a folder inside the `src` folder named `PackagedComponent` which will contain 2 files `PackagedComponent.jsx` and `index.js`.

Our component will be very simple

```js
import React from 'react`;

export const PackagedComponent = () => {
  return (
    <h1>This is my packaged component!</h1>
  );
}
```

The `index.js` will serve as the **starting point**

```js
export { PackagedComponent } from './PackagedComponent';
```

Next we have to do is create a repository on Gitlab and link it to the project we just have created. We then create a `.npmrc` file in the root directory of our application. This is optional but I find this really easy since there is a good [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/) on Gitlab for that. My `.npmrc` file looks like that

```
# Add token for uploading to the registry. Replace <your_project_id>
# with the project you want your package to be uploaded to.
# The auth toke is only necessary if you have a private package

//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/< your_project_id>/packages/npm/:_authToken="< your_auth_token>"
```

Next thing we do is to create the `package.json` for the project and therefore we do

```
npm init
```

Just go with all the standard options for the moment.

#### The packaging

Now it's time to do the actual building and packaging. First we have to install some more dev dependencies which will do the transpiling for us ( I will not explain all that but check [here](https://medium.com/@revanth0212/how-to-create-and-publish-react-components-using-the-create-react-app-9d60583c2161) for further infos)

```
npm i --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0
```

Now we have to modify the `package.json`. First remove the line

```
"private: true"
```

then replace the **build command**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf dist && NODE_ENV=production npx babel src/PackagedComponent --out-dir dist --copy-files",
  ...
},
```

then add the lines

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"module": "dist/index.js",
"files": "/dist",
"babel": {
   "presets": [ "react", "env", "stage-0" ]
}
```

change the `name` to fit the scope. In my case I have created a group which contains my `packaged-component` project. The **group name** in this case is the scope `@group-name/packaged-component-package`.

```
"name": "@group-name/packaged-component-package",
```

Gitlab requires a `publishConfig` so we have to add

```
"publishConfig": {
  "@group-name:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<your_project_id>/packages/npm/"
}
```

be careful that you get the `scope` and the `project id` right!

Now we just have to install the missing packages

```
npm i
```

run the build command

```
npm run build
```

and publish to Gitlab

```
npm publish
```

If everything went well, you should see you package in your group on Gitlab under **Packages & Registries**.

#### Adding the component to another application

Now we want to use our packaged component in another application. We can just run `npx create-react-app test-app` again. In the app directory add a `.npmrc` again

```
# Set URL for your scoped packages.
@group-name:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/

# Add the token for the scoped packages URL. This will allow you to download
# `@foo/` packages from private projects.
# You only need this if the package is private
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken="<your_auth_token>"
```

Once this is done run `npm i` and your Component should appear in the `node_modules` directory under `@group-name/packaged-component-package`.

Then open the `App.js` and add the lines

```
import './App.css';

// import the packaged component
import { PackagedComponent } from '@group-name/packaged-component-package';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PackagedComponent />
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Ideally you should see the following screen

[image]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Just update for .npmrc file in destination project. Instead of: "@group-name:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/" you should change to: "@group:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/your-project-id/packages/npm/"